# Using ANN for Multiple Regression in Python (Keras)

Tags: python, neural-network, deep-learning, keras

I wish to use the Keras package in Python to perform a prediction task. For each observation, I have measurements of 4 (continuous) independent variables (my X) and 1 (continuous) dependent variable (my y). y is generally a value between -10 and +10 though there are measurements of y in the data outside this range. When I ran the code below (and some later code to generate the predictions on the test set), the ANN was predicting the same output irrespective of what x-values it was supplied (when of course really I want the model to give different predictions when supplied a set of dependent variables with different values). The dataset in question concerns rounds of golf and I have circa. 450,000 observations (x-y pairs). I am trying to predict how well players will play in their next round.

Clearly I don't *need* to be using an ANN for this but I wanted to explore what it was capable of.

Here is my code:

```
# Importing the Keras libraries and packages
import keras
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense

X = dataset.iloc[:, 3:7].values
y = dataset.iloc[:, 13].values

# Splitting the dataset into the Training set and Test set
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.2, random_state = 0)

# Feature Scaling
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
sc = StandardScaler()
X_train = sc.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test = sc.transform(X_test)

# Initialising the ANN
classifier = Sequential()

# Adding the input layer and the first hidden layer
classifier.add(Dense(units = 6, kernel_initializer = 'uniform', activation = 'relu', input_dim = 4))

# Adding the second hidden layer
classifier.add(Dense(units = 3, kernel_initializer = 'uniform', activation = 'relu'))

# Adding the output layer
classifier.add(Dense(units = 1, kernel_initializer = 'uniform'))

# Compiling the ANN
classifier.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'mse', metrics = ['ame'])

# Fitting the ANN to the Training set
classifier.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size = 10, epochs = 5)
```

Comment: Is your loss decreasing? Did you try train for more than just 5 epochs? Also, add a linear or relu activation on the output layer

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: I trained for only two epochs but that is because there were about 350,000 examples in the test set. At the end of both of these, the loss and the cost function were printed and they were the same. So, believing the neural network had successfully optimised the weights, I used it to predict X_test, which I had held back. And the prediction it gave for every example in X_test was also exactly the same! This just cannot be correct because there are some predictor variables that correlate very strongly with y - it's not as if the data is random.